# Dimmer switch gets very warm - almost hot

Tags: wiring, lighting, installation, dimmer-switch

I recently had a Z-wave dimmer switch installed. It is working fine and controls the recessed lighting in my family room. The lights are six 65-watt BR40 bulbs.

When the cover was off the switch (we were painting) I noticed that the outside of the switch (the metal tabs and screw) get very, very warm, almost hot to the touch.

Is that normal? 
Additionally, if I replaced the bulbs with LED bulbs, which would use a lot less wattage, would that reduce the current going through the switch and make it not heat up as much?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

What is the wattage rating of the switch? Many dimmers are 300 watts (or less if they are trimmed to fit in crowded boxes). You are burning 390 watts. You may be overloading the switch.

Your instincts about LEDs is correct, assuming the switch is LED compatible. You also need to be sure to select dimmable LED bulbs.

Comment: > What is the wattage rating of the switch? bib, thank you for answering my question. The manual says the following: Maximum Loads: 600W, 2-gang 500W or 3-gang 400W incandescent, 150W CFL/LED

Comment: @Gummy, it's quite possible this is normal behavior, especially if you've got it ganged with other switches and it's loaded to 390W. Is it just very warm, or is it actually too hot to touch?

Comment: If the switch is _not_ LED-compatible, but is used with dimmable LED bulbs, could that in itself cause overheating of the switch?

Comment: Actually, I'll make that a separate question.